# Get value from previous hour and subtract from current value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to subtract level value from previous hour max(date)'s level value but I'm confused on how to get the last record and subtract it hour-wise.

My table records are like this:

```
SNO | Date                     | ID    | Level
1   | 2021-01-13 00:07:44.190  | 1021  | 56.29
2   | 2021-01-13 00:33:44.190  | 1022  | 84.29
3   | 2021-01-13 00:35:44.190  | 1021  | 54.29
4   | 2021-01-13 00:43:44.190  | 1021  | 53.29
5   | 2021-01-13 00:47:44.190  | 1022  | 82.29
6   | 2021-01-13 01:07:44.190  | 1021  | 52.93
7   | 2021-01-13 01:33:44.190  | 1022  | 82.29
8   | 2021-01-13 01:43:44.190  | 1021  | 47.29
9   | 2021-01-13 01:47:44.190  | 1022  | 79.29
10  | 2021-01-13 02:07:44.190  | 1021  | 44.29
11  | 2021-01-13 02:33:44.190  | 1022  | 77.29
```

Now what I need to do is I need max(date) from each hour on the basis of ID whose results are like this:

```
SNO | Date                     | ID    | Level | Level_2
3   | 2021-01-13 00:43:44.190  | 1021  | 53.29 | <-- Level from previous last hour or 0 -->
4   | 2021-01-13 00:47:44.190  | 1022  | 82.29 | <-- Level from previous last hour or 0 -->
7   | 2021-01-13 01:43:44.190  | 1021  | 47.29 | 54.29
8   | 2021-01-13 01:47:44.190  | 1022  | 79.29 | 82.29
9   | 2021-01-13 02:07:44.190  | 1021  | 44.29 | 47.29
10  | 2021-01-13 02:33:44.190  | 1022  | 77.29 | 79.29
```

Kindly please share possible results for this condition and you can ask for more information if needed.

Comment: I don't really follow.  What is being subtracted?

Comment: Subtracting previous hour level value from the next hour level value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the results you want, you can filter down to the last row in each hour and then use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(level) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_level
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id 
                                order by convert(date, date), datepart(hour, date) order by date desc
                               ) as seqnm
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that you have data for every hour.

Another method is to look at the *next* date and see if it is in the same hour.

An alternative way to get data for every hour is to use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date is null or
      datediff(hour, date, next_date) > 0;
```